# Rails 3.2.2 mysql2 adapter Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2

I've been having trouble getting the mysql2 adapter working with the latest version of rails. I Just generated a new project. Added the following to my gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3.7'
```

then of course ran:

```
bundle install
```

I also modified my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: blog_development
  username: root
  password: *********
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: blog_test
  username: root
  password: ********
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: blog_production
  username: root
  password: *********
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

So when I try and run rake db:create, the following is the output.

```
$ rake db:create --trace
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.3.6. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.)
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:157:in `block in replace_gem'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:48:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:27:in `spec'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:67:in `create_database'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `each'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/teddyknox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

It's telling me to install:

```
gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
```

But this gem doesn't exist. I'm pretty confused. I've tried many different versions of mysql2 and none seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Using the following in the gemfile seemed to work:

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like one of your gems requires `mysql2 ~> 0.3.10` (meaning >= 0.3.10 && < 0.4), while you are requiring it < 0.3.7. Try removing the constraint on the version and `bundle install` again ?

Comment: It seems there's a small window of mysql2 version range that's compatible with rails 3.2.2. I may have just found it with "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11".